# How can c# exception handling be localised without excessive nesting?

Tags: c#

I'm learning c# and struggling to write good error handling code. For example, when opening and reading a file, it seems difficult to do error handling which is localised to where the error occurs. Take the following (much simplified) example:

```
        private static void ReadFile(string path) {
            try {
                using var fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
                using var sr = new StreamReader(fs, Encoding.ASCII);

                var line = string.Empty;
                while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null) {
                    // Actions performed on each line here
                    Console.WriteLine(line);
                }
            }
            catch (IOException) {
                Console.Error.WriteLine("Exception");
                return;
            }
        }
```

In the code above, the `catch` statement will catch any `IOException` raised whilst opening or reading the file. In a real world application there could also be other I/O operations within the main loop which could raise the same exception.

However, I would like to handle errors raised when opening the file differently from errors whilst reading the file so I would like different error handling code for each I/O operation.

How can I narrow down the scope of the `try`/`catch` so that it just catches exceptions during file opening? If I put the `using` statements in their own `try`/`catch` block like this:

```
try {
    using var fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    using var sr = new StreamReader(fs, Encoding.ASCII);
catch (IOException) {
    // etc.
```

it doesn't work because they go out of scope at the end of the block.

Comment: `The error handling is far away from where the error may have occurred` - no, the error handling is right after the block any line of which may have caused the error. `I may wish to handle errors differently depending on where they occur` - then wrap each such *where* in its own `try`/`catch`.

Comment: Replace `IOException` with `Exception`. `IOException` is a specific exception, and will not catch other types of exceptions, whereas `Exception` will catch all exceptions.

Comment: @Ergis No. You should _never_ catch Exception. It's very bad style (because you could hide programming errors, such as NullReferenceException or ArgumentOutOfRangeException)

Comment: Note that realistically, only the `new FileStream()` line can throw an Exception. There's nothing else that can fail here.

Comment: @PMF You can always rethrow. And also that is to be discussed. My point is, you jumping on me, chill for that. I only commented that because I had the doubt the OP was getting confused why other exceptions are not being cought in the catch block, so I replied that you are catching a SPECIFIC exception...

Comment: @Ergis Ah ok. Doesn't seem to be the confusion here. He's merely trying to be as specific as possible, I think.

Comment: @GSerg By "far away" I mean that the code which catches errors occurring during the file open operation is located below the code which processes the file content. "Wrap each such where in it's own `try`/`catch` - this results in the excessive nesting I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: @PMF "realistically, only the new FileStream() line can throw an Exception" - not really. File reads can fail - especially if the file is located elsewhere on the network. Defensive coding techniques require that every file operation or other operation on an external resource has its own error handling.